# Plot a FITS image over a grid of the entire sky

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, astropy

I would like to plot a FITS image over a sketch of the entire sky.

I got this far in plotting the entire sky:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.utils.data import get_pkg_data_filename
from astropy.io import fits

image_file = get_pkg_data_filename('tutorials/FITS-images/HorseHead.fits')
image_data = fits.getdata(image_file, ext=0)

plt.subplot(111, projection='aitoff')
plt.grid(True)
plt.imshow(image_data, cmap='gray')
plt.show()
```

But I can't seem to get the FITS image properly aligned with the grid

---

The above code results in the following
[image: actual result]
But I'm trying to get something more like
[image: expected result]
where the blue square is the actual position of the image in `image_file`

Comment: Can you show actual and expected results?

Comment: That's a `mollweide` projection, not an `aitoff` projection.

Comment: @HS-nebula are you talking about the second image? A Mollweide is pseudocylindrical, and thus has parallel horizontal lines for the RA. Both the above images look like an Aitoff to me

Answer (score 4):

The `image_data` is just an array of pixel values, and doesn't actually contain any information about the positions and orientations of the pixels on a sky map. You have to extract that information from the FITS file too.

An example would be (based in information from [here](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/visualization/wcsaxes/index.html) and [here](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/visualization/wcsaxes/custom_frames.html)):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy.utils.data import get_pkg_data_filename
from astropy.io import fits
from astropy.wcs import WCS
from astropy.visualization.wcsaxes.frame import EllipticalFrame

image_file = get_pkg_data_filename('tutorials/FITS-images/HorseHead.fits')
image_header = fits.open(image_file)[0].header  # extract header info
image_data = fits.getdata(image_file, ext=0)

# use the WCS class to get coordinate info and projection axes to use
wcs = WCS(image_header)

# make the axes using the EllipticalFrame class
ax = plt.subplot(projection=wcs, frame_class=EllipticalFrame)

# add the image
im = ax.imshow(image_data, origin='lower')

# add a grid
overlay = ax.get_coords_overlay('fk5')
overlay.grid(color='white', ls='dotted')
```

[image: plot of horsehead nebula]

As the particular image example doesn't extend across the whole sky you'll only see a small patch (but you can extend the plot using `ax.set_xlim()` and `ax.set_ylim()` as required, although I'm not sure what the units are, and it's also worth noting that this image actually just covers a very small patch of sky), but if your image was over the whole sky it would look like an Aitoff projection as shown [here](http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/visualization/wcsaxes/custom_frames.html).

I think this only works with the latest version of astropy (v3.1), Matplotlib (v3.0.2), and therefore requires Python >= 3.5.

You may also want to look at [healpy](https://healpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html), although that can't read in the astropy example FITS file.

Comment: But how do I extend the grid beyond the frame of the image?

Comment: You can use `ax.set_xlim()` and `ax.set_ylim()` although I'm not sure what units the limits are in (potentially something like arcseconds). So, if you do `ax.set_xlim((-180*60, 180*60))` and `ax.set_ylim((-90*60, 90*60))` you'll start to see more (but not the whole) of the sky. Note that this image actually covers a very small bit of the sky, so if you have the whole sky it will just look like a dot.

Comment: But that leaves the image centered on the horsehead nebula rather than on the coordinate (0,0) point

Comment: I'm afraid it's hit the limit of my knowledge. You could also have a look at trying [aplpy](https://aplpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), although the documentation is a bit limited and I couldn't get it to work. Or it might be worth asking the question on the astropy forum http://www.astropy.org/contribute.html